# How can I do this update query in ruby with sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I have table `blogs` and I want to add one to column `views` when user enter to the blog page .

```
DB[:blogs].where(:id => params[:id]).update(:views => :views + 1)
```

but it gave me error when I enter to the blog page in +

undefined method `+' for :views:Symbol

I'm do this :

```
blog = DB[:blogs].where(:id => params[:id]).first
views = blog[:views] + 1
DB[:blogs].where(:id => params[:id]).update(:views => views)
```

but this is add 3 or 5 or 1 or 4 not 1 only

Answer (score 1):

(The question has nothing about Sinatra, just Sequel, which is not a part of Sinatra, but rather standalone library.)

You can do this:

```ruby
DB[:blogs].where(:id => params[:id]).
  update(Sequel.expr(:views) => Sequel.expr(:views) + 1)
```

Or just this:

```ruby
DB[:blogs].where(:id => params[:id]).
  update('views = views + 1')
```

Comment: I was try it but it is add 3 or 2 or 5 in 1 refresh not 1 , can you help me ?

Comment: Now, THIS problem, I assume, is really related to Sinatra. Could you please show more of your application, and describe how you receive thouse multiple additions?

Comment: Show your router page Entries very unusual entry in the retrieval and presentation of very unusual. 

But when you enter the entry of the home page that is adding 1 when reloading the page from within the entry "F5" or "Refresh" will add more than 1, for example, adds a 4 or 3 or 2 or 5 or 6 this is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Rails is mostly syntactic sugar, not a woodoo magic. In your case the most efficient way to perform a task is:

```
DB[:blogs].update_all("views = views + 1", ["id = ?", params[:id]])
```

This would generate the query (say `id = 1`):

```
UPDATE "blogs" SET views = views + 1 WHERE (id = 1)
```

Comment: but I'm using sinatra , and your syntax gave me error